# How to moq Linq extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to moq an object in which it will be requerable in my test class. I couldn't do it because apperently moq dosen't moq static methods.

```
    var mockConfiguration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
    mockConfiguration.Setup(f => f.AsEnumerable()
                                      .Where(kvp => kvp.Key.StartsWith($"CheckerConfigurations:{nameof(OSVersionChecker)}:SupportedVersions:") && kvp.Value != null)
                                      .Select(kvp => kvp.Value)).Returns(new List<string>() {
                                          "Android 5",
                                          "Android 6",
                                          "Darwin Kernel Version 15",
                                          "Darwin Kernel Version 16",
                                          "Windows 10",
                                          "Windows 6.2",
                                          "Windows 6.3"
                                      }.AsEnumerable());
```

Can anyone show me how to do it please ?

Comment: You have to change your method to not static. Make this method virtual or let class it belongs to implement an interface

Comment: Instead of trying to mock extension methods why not setup the IConfiguration class to contain the test data you expect?

Comment: @FCin Can you tell me what method are you talking about please ? because all 'im trying to mock are extensions from Linq which are static per definition

Comment: @DarrenLamb IConfiguration is not a class I created, it's in fact in the namespace  Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. Soo are you suggesting that i add an extension method to this class that do for me the query ?
If so wouldn't i be in the same problem since all the extension methods are static

Comment: Not at all. From what I gather here you're trying to ensure that your mockConfiguration returns values you expect? You don't need to mock the linq methods to achieve this. What I'm suggesting is you populate the mockConfiguration object with test data and leave the linq methods to perform as designed.

Comment: @DarrenLamb I'm really new to C# and Linq and Unit tests can you please  explain your idea ? what do you mean by populate mockConfiguration.Object ?
I've tried to do  mockConfiguration.Object.AsEnumerable()...= new List<string>.... but it didn't work, i got "the left hand side of an assignment should be variable property or indexer"

Answer (score 2):

You can't mock static methods and so all LINQ methods are not (easy) mockable (in fact it is possible, due to ordering of namespaces and which extension method will be picked), but that is not what you like to do.

Instead you should create an instance (regardless if mocked or real) which provides the desired data and inject this into the methods you like to test.

In case of [`IConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/) there is even no mock needed. You can use an existing implementation that provides the desired data.

So for your case i would use the following one:

```
[Fact]
public void ConfigurationContainsSupportedVersions()
{
    var config = CreateConfiguration();
    var items = config.GetSection($"CheckerConfigurations:{nameof(OSVersionChecker)}:SupportedVersions").Get<List<string>>();

    Assert.Equal(7, items.Count);
}

private static IConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
{
    return new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
        { $"CheckerConfigurations:{nameof(OSVersionChecker)}:SupportedVersions:0", "Android 5" },
        { $"CheckerConfigurations:{nameof(OSVersionChecker)}:SupportedVersions:1", "Android 6" },
        { $"CheckerConfigurations:{nameof(OSVersionChecker)}:SupportedVersions:2", "Darwin Kernel Version 15" },
        { $"CheckerConfigurations:{nameof(OSVersionChecker)}:SupportedVersions:3", "Darwin Kernel Version 16" },
        { $"CheckerConfigurations:{nameof(OSVersionChecker)}:SupportedVersions:4", "Windows 10" },
        { $"CheckerConfigurations:{nameof(OSVersionChecker)}:SupportedVersions:5", "Windows 6.2" },
        { $"CheckerConfigurations:{nameof(OSVersionChecker)}:SupportedVersions:6", "Windows 6.3" },
        })
        .Build();
}
```

This `config` instance can be forwarded to any method that consumes an IConfiguration and it produces the desired output you like.